# Should I post Flash exe to web?

Tags: flash

Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with audio and video on the Web.

I've been given a Flash tutorial to post to the corporate website that is an .exe file with an embedded Flash player. Users will be on IE, so I guess they would get the run/save prompt.

I don't like this and I know it generally isn't done, but I need to know if it is OK to just do it. When I try to explain the security issues with executable files, eyes glaze. Is it possible that the users' system admins would be able to block the run prompt and make the user save the file? Could they block that too? The user community is hopeless, so having the embedded Flash player could be a good thing.

Comment: Kinda leave linux & mac users in the dark to do that. Flash is intended to run cross-platform, but if you're 100% sure everybody will be using windows there's no real issue.

Comment: Mac and Linux would still have the download option though, right?

This is a legacy app that only runs on IE. I'm slowly fixing the JavaScript issues that will make it cross-platform, but this tutorial will be a non-issue by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any executable can be blocked by corporate IT policy. That said, there is nothing inherently wrong with publishing a .exe file. That's how shareware is distributed, after all, and most commercial software as well. *Caveat emptor*.

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda what I thought, but it is good to have it confirmed.